# What is a good approach for migrating from LINQ to SQL to DocumentDB?

Tags: sql-server, azure, linq-to-sql, database-migration, azure-cosmosdb

First, a little background to our situation.  Several years ago I started an ASP.NET MVC project using LINQ to SQL as the DAL.  Being the only developer on the project at the time, I chose to use it because it was pretty well supported in the community and I needed to focus more on the application logic and UI design so I could get it to market.  That strategy worked out quite well for us.

It wasn't long, though, until I needed to write some multi-threaded code in a Windows service against the same data store.  LINQ to SQL encountered all sorts of problems with crossing threads.  Still being the only developer at the time and needing to get this service up quickly, I resorted to duplicating just enough of the DAL and models using POCOs and Enterprise Library.  Though not ideal architecture with duplicate models and DAL functionality, it worked well enough and got me through.

That was five years ago.  We've been successful with our project to the point where that very success is now a liability not with LINQ or Enterprise Library, but with SQL itself.  Now, before anyone suggests that we give our SQL database an overhaul with indexes and all of that, we have done exactly that.  We added a DBA on contract and he solved the problem for us.  Performance was restored and things were okay.  The problem, though is that it requires (in our opinion) too frequent maintenance for our business model and requirements.

Thankfully, Microsoft has stepped up their game with Azure services.  Of specific interest to us (we have two developers now), is DocumentDB.  In SQL we have several large, flat, busy tables that give some areas of our application severe performance problems when we start to approach the need for DB maintenance.  We simply don't have the resources to devote to ongoing maintenance.  We've decided to move our application either in part or entirely to DocumentDB.  A few proof of concept demos internally tell us that this is a good move for the type of application we have.

If you've read this far, thank you, and here is my question.  What would be a good way to migrate the LINQ to SQL classes and generated logic to a DAL backed by DocumentDB?  Thankfully, I had the foresight early on to use an IRepository approach such that the application itself won't be impacted, hopefully at all.  I'm mostly concerned with all of the "magic" CRUD stuff that the LINQ to SQL design surface coded for me.  My other developer and I certainly understand how to write our own DAL code, but we need a quick and consistent approach that takes into account the behavior that the application is coded to expect from having been backed by LINQ to SQL.

My instinct is to basically unwind all of the generated code that LINQ to SQL did for me five years ago and divorce it from the LINQ to SQL designer, add in our own DAL via DI and go from there. My other developer is more advanced than I am on that part of things, so I have a pretty decent amount of confidence that we can get it done.  Just hoping somebody out there can help us avoid pitfalls so we can get this done efficiently.

Comment: I should also add that I'm concerned about how to maintain the relationships that LINQ to SQL keeps among entities.  One thing I really like about LINQ to SQL is that you can rely on parent-child relationships to be kept track of in the data context.  In the application, you can easily add, remove, or change child entities, call a single update method and all of those relationships are honored without any fuss and minimal code.  Ideally, that is the behavior we'd like to preserve in a DocumentDB DAL.

Comment: If you have been making non-trivial use of RDBMS and ORM features you'll find that the migration comes close to a rewrite. DocumentDB does not offer you a way to replace many RDBMS queries in an efficient way. You can't push join to the database for example (DocDB has only same-document joins AFAIK). Therefore, your existing IRepository abstraction is not going to help you much. Further, I would question the need to switch to DocDB because you get less features and less performance out of it. Rather, simplify your use of the database and fix problems.

Comment: Often, people switch to NoSQL and claim that perf improved. But what really improved perf was a simpler data model that the RDBMS would also have provided.

Comment: Yeah, I considered that effect as well, and I'm sure it will prove out to some extent.  However, our contract DBA monitored the SQL at the database level on the main trouble areas and discovered only 1 out of 5 areas where the application was clearly at fault.  Once he optimized and rebuilds the indexes, the application flies like day 1.

Comment: As far as coming close to a re-write, I think you're right on the money with that comment.  That's what I'm sensing, which is why I wanted to throw this out there for scrutiny before we dive into it.

Comment: It appears my comments have been deleted for a reason unknown to me. my recommendation was to simply rebuild all indexes regularly in an automated way because, as you say, after rebuilding indexes the performance problems are gone. Does that solve your problem? If yes I'll make it into an answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, but I may have overreacted.  It looked as if you were promoting a product and one that didn't address the solution I was seeking an answer to.  Rebuilding the indexes, even in an automated way, is simply not a good long-term strategy for us.  I apologize that I didn't specify that in my question at large.  Even when the indexes are rebuilt, only the most severe problems go away.  We still have an issue of scale that would otherwise require professional SQL resources (DBA, more hardware, etc).  Azure is where we are going to go, just wanted to know a good way to get there.

Comment: OK. If you are going on Azure SQL performance might take a 10-100x hit due to various limits being enforced (for example tiny buffer pool cache in combination with a severely throttled IO system). I see astounded questions about that all the time here. So indeed, that makes the NoSQL stores on Azure more attractive because the built-in SQL is crippled to uselessness. Anyway, that's all I have to add to this question (basically: Don't do it if you can at all help it, SQL is not the root cause. Bad queries are the root cause. Rewrite the queries and schema, not the data store).

Comment: So, this question is really broad and opinion-based. There is no single right answer. And looking through the comments, there are already suggestions around sticking with SQL, and other comments suggesting migrating to DocDB. And everything in between. This is a good discussion, but I don't see it as a good fit for StackOverflow since there's no right answer to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David Makogon points out in a comment, this question really has no "correct" answer as it is very broad and opinion-based.  I'm getting a broad range of suggestions, but nothing I would consider a definitive answer.